# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function in knockout

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I am trying to implement a filter functionality in a html table generated through knockout for each binding with the help of following code.

```
self.filteredStep1Records = ko.computed(function() {
            return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.step1BundleData(), function(bundle) {
                self.pageNumber(0);
                return (self.searchText().length == 0 || bundle.id.toLowerCase().indexOf(self.searchText().toLowerCase()) !== -1 || bundle.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(self.searchText().toLowerCase()) !== -1);
            });
        });
```

I am getting error as 
"Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" at following line:

```
return (self.searchText().length == 0 || bundle.id.toLowerCase().indexOf(self.searchText().toLowerCase()) !== -1 || bundle.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(self.searchText().toLowerCase()) !== -1);
```

Rest of the code includes:

```
this.searchText = ko.observable('');
this.step1BundleData = ko.observableArray();
function bundle(id,name){
            this.id = ko.observable(id);
            this.name = ko.observable(name);
            this.selected = ko.observable(false);
        }
```

Following Ajax request is used to create bundle:

```
getdata(8).done(function(data){
            data = $.parseJSON(data);
            $.each(data,function(index,value){
                self.step1BundleData.push(new bundle(value.id,value.name));
            });
        });
```

I am not sure where I am going wrong.

Comment: Can you provide some more context to the snippets? How is `self.searchText` defined? Can you provide sample data for a `bundle` from `self.step1BundleData()`? Are `bundle.id` and `bundle.name` always `String`s?

Comment: @Jonathan I have edited question with more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Being defined as `ko.observable`s...

```
function bundle(id,name){
    this.id = ko.observable(id);
    this.name = ko.observable(name);
    this.selected = ko.observable(false);
}
```

...the `id` and `name` of each `new bundle` [will be `function`s that you'll have to invoke](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html#reading-and-writing-observables) to retrieve the value.

```
... || bundle.id().toLowerCase().indexOf(...
//              ^^
```

Similar to how you're invoking `self.searchText` to retrieve its value:

```
return (self.searchText().length == 0 || ...
//                     ^^
```

The `function`s themselves won't have a `toLowerCase()` method.

```
console.log(typeof bundle.name);               // 'function'
console.log(typeof bundle.name.toLowerCase);   // 'undefined'

console.log(typeof bundle.name());             // 'string'
console.log(typeof bundle.name().toLowerCase); // 'function'
```

---

```
return (self.searchText().length == 0 || bundle.id().toLowerCase().indexOf(self.searchText().toLowerCase()) !== -1 || bundle.name().toLowerCase().indexOf(self.searchText().toLowerCase()) !== -1);
```